# How to debug a stackoverflow problem on targets

Tags: c, debugging, stack-overflow

I want to know how do we proceed to debug a STACKOVERFLOW issue on targets .
I mean what are the steps we should follow to reach a conclusion.

Comment: What do you mean "targets"?  We need more info.

Comment: i put target to make it generic ...but my issue is for ARM 7,9 processors.
Suppose i have Lauterback and trace32 available

Answer (score 1):

Put a memory write watchpoint for one word past the end of your stack space.  Then the debugger will break in when that spot gets written to, and you can see what's at fault.

Answer (score 1):

All stacks can be filled at start up with certain hex value (for example 0xAAAAAAAA). And then using special routine you can monitor all stack's maximum usage periodically by calculating the quantity of known values (0xAA..) from end of stack until finds the first difference.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through a debugger such as gdb. The backtrace at the time of the stack overflow will tell you exactly which function or functions are repeating indefinitely. From there, figure out which input(s) to those functions are not changing, and not moving the function (if it's recursive) towards a base-case that will end the recursion.